# What is the meaning of this tag: <t>lorem ipsum</t>

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

The template page http://www.blacktie.co/demo/kelvin contains a tag I haven't seen before: `<t>Email</t>`

The corresponding CSS styles this: `#footwrap t {font-weight: 700;}`

I'm curious as to the significance of the `<t>`. It's not listed at http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags or other lists I can find.

Is this a custom HTML tag? From what I've read about custom elements (eg http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements) you need to call `document.registerElement()` or `document.createElement()` but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Is this code semantically correct, or should it be written as:

```
<span class="t">Email</span>

#footwrap .t {font-weight: 700;}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the `<t>` tag is a custom element. While custom tags can be useful, if you want them supported in all browsers, you have to register the element with JS:

```
var tTag = document.registerElement('t');
```

[More about custom tags here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)
So to answer your question, the coding is not valid, *unless* they have registered the element with the browser with JavaScript.
Sometimes, its just easier to use a `class` :D

Answer (score 0):

This may be completely wrong, but **t** is not a real HTML tag. Therefor I assume it is a XHTML item. So yes if it IS XHTML then that would be correct, and the class would not be (unless that was the name of it of course).